# What does colon infront of a variable mean?

Tags: ruby

```
class Library
  attr_accessor :games
  def initialize(games)
    @games = games
  end
end
```

How comes there is a colon infront of `games`?

Whenever I research what the `:` means I usually find articles where people say its a symbol, then give a very ambiguous definition of what a symbol is.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers OP knows it is a symbol. But `attr_accessor :games` might confused..

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers If so, I will down my answer now.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I apologize. I wanted to know what : means in the context of attr_accessor.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 You are too late to mention it.. :- when you will be asking question, please be around there, so that you can reply promptly to help those people, who wants to help you out. This is not an advice, rather a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it simple: symbols are nothing more than a name for a constant. The value is irrelevant, but only symbols with the same name share the same value:

> Symbol objects represent names [...] inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the `:name` and `:"string"` literals syntax, and by the various `to_sym` methods.

See [Ruby docs on Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html) for more details.

The usual use cases for symbols include:

- keys for hashes (`hsh[:foo] 0 42; hsh[:foo] #=> 42`)
- method or variable names, since those types of objects are not first-class citizens of Ruby (there is a `Method` class representing a method, but that's something different)

---

Please note, that symbols won't be garbage collected, unlike strings. That means, you should avoid code like

```
key = :"oh-my-#{bar}" # like string interpolation
```

when `bar` is build from user (attacker) generated input.

---

In the case of `attr_accessor`, the parameter (`:games` in your case), creates an instance variable with the same name (`@games`) plus a setter and getter method (let `l = Library.new`, then the setter `l.games=(val)` and the getter `l.games` become available).

Comment: Soon symbols will be able to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

Instances of [Symbol class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html). However it's mentioned and explained in all tutorials or beginner guides I've seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

The colon indicates the variable is a symbol. Symbols are Strings, with one important difference, Symbols are immutable. Mutable objects can be changed after assignment while immutable objects can only be overwritten.